# Firebase problems when reading long data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Android studio. Java. 
in Firebase I write down the object of my class. The class contains a field of type long. In the console, the firebase data is written correctly. But when reading data, the field of type long gets an empty value, and all other fields are read correctly.
In what can be proleuma and how to fix it?

This is an object class that is stored in firebase:

```
public class MovementsClass {
    private int Kind;                                   //тип записи: доход/расход
    //private byte Repeatability;                         //повторяемость записи
    private double Value;                                 //сумма движения
    private long DateInMilisec;
    private String Name;

    public MovementsClass() { }

    public int getKind() {
        return Kind;
    }
    public double getValue() {
        return Value;
    }
    public long getDateInMilisec() {
        return DateInMilisec;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }


  public void setKind(int Kind) {
    this.Kind = Kind;
}
public void setCurrentDate() {
    this.DateInMilisec = new Date().getTime();
```

This is the procedure for reading the data:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        CurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mDBref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(CurrentUser.getUid()).child("Movements");

        mBDMovements = new ArrayList<>(0);
        mDBref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //GenericTypeIndicator <ArrayList<MovementsClass>> MoveList = new GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<MovementsClass>>(){};
                mBDMovements.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    mBDMovements.add(snapshot.getValue(MovementsClass.class));
                }
                //mBDMovements = dataSnapshot.child(CurrentUser.getUid()).child("Movements").getValue(MoveList);
                mAdapter = new MovementsListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mBDMovements);   // каждый раз при обновлении данных?
                setListAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
```

In the variable mBDMovements.DateInMilisec gets 0:

[image: debugger]

Comment: can you show the firebase database structure?

Comment: I solved my problem today.
The mistake was that the class did not specify a setter for the field.
Thank you